# Img element from Vue.js component is not rendered into Laravel production environment

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I am compiling an `img element` for production with `npm run prod` from `resources/images` dir. The compilation is done with `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css').vue();
```

Bottom of `welcome.blade.php`:

```
<body id="body">
  <div id="app">
    <app></app>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

The `img element` is inside a `vue component`:

```
  <img :src="require('../images/portrait.png')" id="portrait" alt="">
```

and gets compiled to `public/images` dir:

[image]

As you can see `portrait.png` is compiled into `public/images`. But as soon as I try to run the app with `php artisan serve` the image is not displayed in the browser. It is the only image not displayed. The browser console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

on initial page load and:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/require(%60../images/portrait.png%60) 404 (Not Found)
```

on page refresh.

According to this [img src thread on github](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/issues/42) `require` should work for `img elements` but it doesn't. Any workaround?

specs:

```
OS: Windows 10
Vue.js: 4.5.13
Laravel: 8.55.0
```

Comment: Stupid question, but have you compiled your vue application? You need some kind of resolver (like webpack) to transpile your dev code into code working in browsers. Browser will not be able to deal with `require` without some kind of compilation or resource loader

Comment: @AramBecker Yes, I've added `webpack.mix.js` and `welcome.blade.php` to the question. Like I said, the images get compiled from `resources/images` to `public/images`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with resolving the image as module. Could you try adding `.default` to the require statement?, e.g.

```
<img :src="require('../images/portrait.png').default" id="portrait" alt="">
```

Reference: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2756

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use
`<img src="images/portrait.png" id="portrait" alt="">` ?

Comment: No, when I try that the `img element` does not even get compiled to `public/images`